# Matrices - memory

Tags: arrays, memory, matrix, byte

Let's say that I have a matrix `A=[];`

I want to know if there is any way to represent it in a way where only the filled blocks must occupy memory and remaining must not, e.g.:

```
A = 1 0 0
    0 1 0
    0 0 1
```

Now, every block would take 1 bit of memory to store the matrix,
hence I would like to know is it possible to store matrix as:

```
 A = 1   
       1
         1
```

and the empty spaces must not occupy any memory at all. Is there any file format to represent a matrix in such a way?

Comment: 0s aren't "empty spaces", they're relevant values that need to be stored. (Even empty spaces aren't "blanks" that don't take memory, the fact that there's space there is important and needs to be stored.)

Answer (score 1):

No. You're dealing with bits. It would take MORE memory to store a list of the "filled" bits than it would to simply store the bits. e.g. for a simple 1x8 matrix:

```
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7   <---bit-wise addresses
m = [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

could be stored as a SINGLE byte of memory, at a storage ratio of 1 bit per bit.

To store just the locations of the SET bits would take 4 bytes. If all of the bits were set, you'd need 8 bytes to store those locations. So now you've got from a constant 1 byte requirement, to a variable 0 -> 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop an way where you can store Informatiosn about the positions in a List but that would at least consummee more memmory as you would win this way. So at least no.